# aquamacs require-final-newline

Tags: html, emacs, aquamacs

I'm using aquatics for rails development and thanks to some inline-block issues I have a situation where I need to render partials without a newline at the end.

The problem is when I save aquamacs always adds a newline to the end of the file.

I have tried adding (setq require-final-newline) in my .emacs file but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the value in the ruby-mode-hook in your emacs init file. For example, for Ruby mode:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                             (setq require-final-newline nil)
                             (setq mode-require-final-newline nil)))
```

EDIT: Ruby mode explicitly sets on "require-final-newline" as a file local variable (which is why your .emacs setting isn't working) so you have to set both variables in the hook. I don't program in Ruby so I'm not sure why the author of ruby-mode sets "require-final-newline" on so there may be some negative side-effects to turning it off. However, the above code should do what you asked for.

Comment: Works for regular GNU emacs & HTML mode as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Ruby mode; didn't realize it hard-coded `require-final-newline`.

Comment: this appears to apply to `web-mode` as well, just apply to `'web-mode-hook`